# Angular not updating data bindings

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to `Angular` and I was implementing sockets to get data from the backend but now when I try to change the value which is being displayed via `{{personaName}}` in the template, the value doesn't update?

When logging it does tell me that the value has changed but when it comes to displaying it its still not displaying the data.

**component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketIoService } from '../../services/socket-io.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  inputs: ['personaName'],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription: Subscription;
  personaName: string;

  private playerSummary;

  constructor(private socket: SocketIoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.socket.playerSummary.subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(this.personaName);
      console.log('Next: %s', x);
      if (x != null) {
        this.playerSummary = JSON.parse(x);
        this.personaName = this.playerSummary["personaname"];
        console.log(this.playerSummary);
        console.log(this.personaName);
      }
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('Error: %s', err);
    },
    () => {
        console.log('Completed');
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use arrow functions - you're losing context with `this` `.subscribe((x) => {`

Comment: @tymeJV sadly, that didn't help, also I added ngOnChanges and tried logging everything in it, nothing outputs when the value change happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `async` pipe in the template and don't subscribe to the `this.socket.playerSummary` observable in the component. Try modifying it to this,

```
observedData: Observable<string>; // assuming this.socket.playerSummary returns an observable

this.observedData = this.socket.playerSummary.map((x) => {
      if (x != null) {
        x = x.json();
        return x["personaname"];
      }
    })
    .catch(err) => {
        console.log('Error: %s', err);
    })
```

Modify your template to this,

```
{{ observedData | async }}
```

I guess you get the idea from this. You might have to refactor/optimize it to make it pass.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was overcomplicating things it seems :)